# How can I insert foreign key id through using channel?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have tables, `Category` and `Subcategory`.

`Category` has many `subcategories` and `Subcategory` belongs to `category`.

In my channel `handle_in`, there is a function to insert subcategory like below.

```
def handle_in("create:subcategory", %{"name" => name, "category_id" => category_id}, socket) do 
changeset = Subcategory.changeset(%Subcategory{name: name, category_id: category_id})
|>Repo.insert

subcategories = from(p in Pos8.Subcategory, select: map(p, [:id, :name, :category_id])) |> Repo.all
response = %{subcategories: subcategories}

  broadcast! socket, "subcategories:updated", response

 {:noreply, socket}
end
```

So basically, what I want to do is to create subcategory with `name` and `category_id` passing. But it triggers a error that `Myapp.Subcategory.category_id in insert does not match type :id
    (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:691: Ecto.Repo.Schema.dump_field!/6
    (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:700: anonymous fn/6 in Ecto.Repo.Schema.dump_fields!/5`

How can I insert `category_id` when I create `subcategory`?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to do a test, you would notice that the `category_id` is a string. This is okay when you are trying to **find** a value in the database using something like `Repo.get/3`, but unfortunately it will not be okay when trying to insert the raw value.

However, you should just be able to do something like `String.to_integer(category_id)` and you will be able to insert it just fine.

So your final insert line would look like

```
changeset = 
  Subcategory.changeset(%Subcategory{name: name, 
                                     category_id: String.to_integer(category_id)})
  |> Repo.insert()
```

As @Dogbert points out in the comments, you can just let the changeset function deal with the conversion.

```
changeset = 
  Subcategory.changeset(%Subcategory{}, %{name: name, category_id: category_id})
  |> Repo.insert()
```

This has the benefit of working not just on integer types.

Comment: Or let `changeset/2` handle the conversion: `Subcategory.changeset(%Subcategory{}, %{name: name, category_id: category_id})`.

Comment: As @Dogbert points out, letting the changeset deal with it is better. Especially since you may not always be dealing with integer ids in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
import Ecto.Changeset
parent = Repo.get!(Category, category_id)
subcategory = cast(%Subcategory{}, %{name: name})
              |> put_assoc(:category, parent) 
              |> Repo.insert!
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this will call the database twice. Once to grab the parent, and again to insert the record.